# Study of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have this function $\displaystyle  g(s)=\frac{s^{2-\sigma}}{1+s^2}, ~\text{for all} ~s\in \mathbb{R}$ , i need to find the interval of $\sigma$ and the maximum of the function $g$.

I calculate the derivative $\displaystyle g'(s)=\frac{s^{1-\sigma}(2-\sigma(1+s^2))}{(1+s^2)^2} $

$g'(s)=0$ implies that $s^{1-\sigma}=0$ or $s^2=\frac{2-\sigma}{\sigma}$

but i canf find where is $\sigma$, for example if it is in $[0,1)$, a what is the maximum of $g$

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: Can you find $\sigma$ as a function of $s$ using your last equation?

Answer (score 1):

First note that you need $2-\sigma>0$ in order to have the function defined for all $s$. Based on your computation, you don't want the critical point at $0$ (since it won't be a maximum), so you need $\dfrac{2-\sigma}{\sigma}>0$. This means we need $0<\sigma<2$. For any such $\sigma$, you now know the critical points, so plug in and find the maximum value.

Comment: i think that $\sigma \in [0,1)$ no ?

Comment: A little remark: note the also the case $\sigma =2$ has to be considered, and in that case the derivative is not the one written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean with finding the interval of $\sigma$. In general the function can have three different kinds of extrema: critical points, singular points and boundary points. Critical points are points where the derivative is equal to zero, and singular points are, in this case, points where the denominator of the function is equal to zero.

edit: Oops, I just saw the `real-analysis` tag. Maybe this hints that a more rigorous answer is needed.

Comment: the interval of $\sigma $ it means that i want to find for example $\sigma\in [0,1)$

Comment: Given the information in your post, you can't really pin $\sigma$ down to any interval. Any $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ would give an equally defined function.